# MonoDevelop .NetFramework 4 Client Profile problem

Tags: monodevelop

I have passed from Windows to Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm happy for my choice.
I have installed MonoDevelop because I am C# programmer and ASP.NET (with MVC3)...

I got a solution from faculty, solution made in Visual Studio 2010 and I opened it in MonoDevelop. The solution opening is fine.

When run the solution, the error occured:
[image]

How to solve this problem ? I am beginner in Ubuntu also in MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the project options, select the general tab and there select the target framework as 4.0 instead of .NETFramework 4.0 ClientProfile.

My project successfully compiled and my project is now running in Mono.

Answer (score 0):

You can change in Preferences --> Save/Load...

Change to open a solution from MS Visual Studio 2010 to MS Visual Studio 2008 or 2005.

Comment: this is no longer an option in Save/Load (monodevelop 5.x)